# My ViewModel does not provide current variable value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, add-in

**[EDIT]** Example reprodoucing this issue [Host to AddIn issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/113376/IssueExample.zip)

I'm trying to write a host application which is extendable and uses few interfaces. One of them is

```
public MessageCreator GetMessageCreator()
{
 var creator = new AVL2MessageCratorFactory();
 return creator.Create(new AVL2DataForMessageCreatingImpl { Imei = VM.Imei });
}
```

from AddIn and below you can find XAML of AddIn guest application:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:AVL2SimulatorAddView="clr-namespace:AVL2SimulatorAddView" x:Class="AVL2SimulatorAddView.AVL2AddInUI">

<Grid Height="46" Width="344">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <AVL2SimulatorAddView:AVL2ViewModel x:Name="VM" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Label Content="Starting IMEI" Margin="0,0,255,0" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Imei,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Margin="120,2,48,0" Width="176" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Imei property from ViewModel

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace AVL2SimulatorAddView
{
 public class AVL2ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    readonly AVL2Model _avl2Model = new AVL2Model();

    public string Imei
    {
        get { return _avl2Model.Imei; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _avl2Model.Imei) return;
            _avl2Model.Imei = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Imei");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

in debug mode I see that property in ViewModel is updated every character is written inside TextBox, but when GetMessageCreator() from Host application is called it seems like new, empty VM and its Imei is returned (I do not see Imei on Host aplication side)

Am I missing some protection in .Net against bypassing bound data? Other "hardcoded" strings are passing well. MVVM and DataContext on Host Application side works well also. I tried different types of UpdateSourceTrigger, but it always seems to work on AddIn side, and it does not provide current date to shared interface.

[EDIT]
Other control bound to Imei, display the changes on-line, when data is entered in textbox

Calling local button set properly the label content

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  label1.Content = VM.Imei;
}
```

Temporary calling method from Host application

```
var msgCreator = _tabsMap[(TabItem) tabControl1.SelectedItem].GetMessageCreator();
```

Comment: What you're describing is not WPF "behaviour", in fact this issue is very odd. It's hard to tell what is going on, I suggest you to put together simple test project to demonstrate this. Paste your whole viewmodel.

Comment: In general in my pasted code this is almost whole ViewModel - only INotifyPropertyChanged member, and _avl2Model (class containing one string property) declaration is missing.
It is hard to prepare example because I think this is connected with AddIn in .Net - all MVVM in my project seperatly works. Even access to VM in this AddIn works and can be bound to another control and updates constantly, or can be directly asked by simple assigment to label Content.

Comment: Who calls the `GetMessageCreator` method an when?

Comment: It is called when I click the button in Host application and the Host application is calling GetMessageCreator belonging to current object. The realtion between Host and AddIn plugin is as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.110).aspx I built my application base on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909849(v=vs.110).aspx
I don't have acces to the code now. I hope that explenaition of relation between Host and AddIn is more clear now.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa I pasted whole ViewModel, AdolfoPerez - on the end I added calling GetMessageCreator from Host application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm referring to your demo project. Consider this code in the constructor of `LoadGeneratorWPFHostApplication.MainWindow`:

```
// Activate creates instance AAddIn#1 (wpfAddInHostView.wpfAddInContract.wpfAddInView)
foreach (var wpfAddInHostView in addInTokens.Select(addInToken => addInToken.Activate<IWpfAddInHostView>(AddInSecurityLevel.Host))) 
{
    // AAddin#1.GetAddinUI creates instance AAddIn#2 (tabItem.Content)
    var tabItem = new TabItem {Content = wpfAddInHostView.GetAddInUI(), Header = wpfAddInHostView.GetName()};  
    tabControl1.Items.Add(tabItem);
    // adding AAddIn#1 to _tabsMap (but using AAddIn#2 on the UI).
    _tabsMap.Add(tabItem, wpfAddInHostView);
}
```

So what happened here is you use `System.AddIn.Hosting.AddInToken.Activate` to create an instance of `AAddIn` (#1). But right after that, you use this AAddIn#1 to create another instance with its method `GetAddInUI`.

```
public partial class AAddIn : WPFAddInView
{
    public FrameworkElement GetAddInUI()
    {
        return new AAddIn(); // creates a new instance of itself
    }
}
```

AAddIn#1 is persisted on the contract (`WPFAddIn_ContractToViewHostSideAdapter.wpfAddInContract.wpfAddInView`) and in `_tabsMap`, AAddIn#2 is used in the UI (`tabItem.Content`).

There are different ways to ensure you keep the same instance, I would probably just remove the `GetAddInUI` method from the `WPFAddInView` interface (note: [always start interface names with an I](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx)) as well as the `AAddIn` class, then return the `wpfAddInView` directly on the contract:

```
public class WPFAddIn_ViewToContractAddInSideAdapter : ContractBase, IWPFAddInContract
{
    public INativeHandleContract GetAddInUI()
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = this.wpfAddInView as FrameworkElement; // return instance directly instead of creating new one by wpfAddInView.GetAddInUI();
        INativeHandleContract inhc = FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(fe);
        return inhc;
    }
}
```

Side note: Use the method `.GetHashCode()` in debugger to differentiate between instances of the same class.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it! I was supposing that it can be two difference instances, but I didn't knew where it can be placed. "I" letter also introduced. 
Maybe you know some way to avoid such issue in future? It is new to me to operate on Host<->contract<->addin solution.

Comment: To me, your problem is not directly related to the managed addin framework pattern, except that the pattern has an inherent complexity. The only advice I could provide in that regard is to keep the interactions between host and addin to a minimum. Whatever you can deal with directly in the addin, do it there. As for the issue itself, you had already guessed that there is a problem with different instances, from there you should really just debug (likely using the `GetHashCode` method as mentioned), trying to find which class is responsible for (creating) different instances.